# Uploading products data from excel file - Amazon MWS

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services

Can someone provide me with the example code for uploading the excel file to amazon MWS ?

Or maybe explain the process, how do I send the excel file to amazon ? Amazon says they support flat file format but they don't provide any example about using it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use MWS to send products, you'll use the [Feeds API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/index.html).  Choose a [FeedType](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html#) from the list of product and inventory feeds and click the XSD or text file templates links to learn about the format.  Once you have the feed formatted, you'll call the [SubmitFeed](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html) operation to upload the feed.  Have a look at the [flowchart](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_Overview.html) to understand the process.

If you download one of the [client libraries](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/162-4298969-3909569?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=feeds&version=latest) in your language of choice, they have all the code you'll need written already, just plug in your account information and have your feed ready to send.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am doing this from last 2 days. The library codes support only one content type "stream-octet". How do I pass flat file in stream ?